# Как переписать код с onclick на addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

Как переписать этот код с onclick на addEventListener?

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="entry.2145715766"]').forEach(el=>el.onclick=e=>{
  document.querySelector('.item_price').textContent = e.target.nextSibling.textContent;
  document.querySelector('.item_Size').textContent = el.value;
});
```

Comment: Заменить el.onclick на el.addEventListener

Comment: Так скрипт работать не будет :)

Comment: Добавьте выше как Вы поменяли :)))

Comment: `addEventListener('event name' , handler)`

Comment: Ребята, я верстальщик, я не знаю что с этим делать. Интегрируйте в полный код пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="entry.2145715766"]').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelector('.item_price').textContent = e.target.nextSibling.textContent;
  document.querySelector('.item_Size').textContent = el.value;
}));
```